# Java: how to lookup bluetooth device?

Tags: java, api, bluetooth

Simple task: find the bluetooth device and define its mac address.
Any Java experience? 
Thanks.

Comment: `On a lighter note` if it is such a simple task why not give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Add more information on which platform you are using - Windows/Linux/Android. If Windows or Linux, you can use [bluecove](http://bluecove.sourceforge.net/) Java library. Note bluecove builds on top of an existing native Bluetooth stack which could be BlueZ on Linux and MS stack on Win. If Android, it has [Java API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).